# Is there a way to globally load icons like when using FontAwesomeIcons and library

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

When using fontawesome icons you are advised to use library.add(...) so they are only loaded once. Now what about svg icons I download myself from elsewhere. Is there a way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a file where you export all your icons from
Eg: `assets/Icons/index.jsx` where you export every icon you will use.

Importing anywhere else import from the file only